# Getting Login information when when sign in to Slack with Google Authentication

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-admin-sdk

I've configured my Slack account with Google Authentication, so users can log in with their  Google accounts. Now, I would like to see a report from Google Workspace that tells me who logged in and when

I've found this API endpoint but it is not returning information from logins on Slack.

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/manage-audit-login#retrieve_login_events_by_event_name

Any idea of how to get this information?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

**Recommendation:**

Since Slack is a third-party web application, you can use the [OAuth Token audit log](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6124308) instead to track which users are using/accessing which third-party mobile or web applications in your domain.

Here's a sample log report on Google Workspace of a user who signed-in to 'Slack':

[image]

Additionally, you can also refer to [Reports API: Authorization Tokens Activity Report](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/manage-audit-tokens) for more infomation on the API side.

Comment: I've tried but it tells me when someone authorizes the access the first time, but after that, when someone log in clicking on "Log in with Google" it does not appears anymore. Any idea?

Comment: As per testing with 2 test user accounts, when I click "Login with Google" option on Slack, I get to see the login info after a few minutes on the Admin Console audit reporting for token. That's kind of odd that "Login with Google" option doesn't show up on your end. Maybe it is due to the Admin Console propagation time of 24 hours at maximum according to https://support.google.com/a/answer/7514107. If it doesn't appear after 24 hours, I suggest to reach out to Google Workspace Support at https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213 to get more insight.

Comment: can you send me a picture of what appears to you? Here, when I register to GitLab with Google,  it appears that: Ralph authorized access to GitLab for https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile, openid scopes

after that, I sign out GitLab and sign in with google and nothing appeared

Comment: Here's a screenshot of the audit log of 2 different users I've tested. I've logged in, logged out and then logged back in a couple of times on Slack at https://imgur.com/a/wzeM2Zd

Comment: I do get information from Slack, but not from another vendor as GitLab. Only when I connect the app not when I login after that, any idea?

Comment: I've tried it and I can also replicate what you're seeing with GitLab & this is odd given that it is also a 3rd party service/app. To be honest, I can't really decipher further as to why succeeding log-ins are no longer tracked for GitLab as I'm also relying on research. Originally, I was hunching it could be related to browser cache but clearing cache and re-logging-in does not log new token on the reports. I'd suggest to reach out to the experts at Workspace support to get more insight about this. This audit reporting behavior could be specific to GitLab but I can't really confirm.